# Infinite Loop on Rock Paper Scissors Game in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, user-input

I have been assigned of developing a Rock Paper Scissors game in Python with some modifications. However, I am quite new to programming, and I do not know how to go about in infinite looping the program unless if the user inputs 'q'. I have a general idea of that I have to use a while loop, however I cannot figure out where to put it.

Attached here is the code that the rock paper scissors game works regularly without trying to infinitely loop and breaking the loop in the program. I have tried to mess around with the indentation of the code after the while loop and had varying results, most of which just broke the program.

```
import random

def play():
    user_option = input("'r for rock:', 'p for paper:', or 's for scissors: or q to quit':")
    cpu = random.choice(['r', 's', 'p'])
    #while user_option != 'y':

    if user_option == cpu:
        return("You tie!")
    if win(user_option, cpu):
        return("You won!")

    return "You lost!"
  
def win(player, computerOpponent):
    if (player == 'r' and computerOpponent == 's') or (player == 's' and computerOpponent == 'p') or (player == 'p' and computerOpponent == 'r'):
        return True

print(play())
```

Comment: you could use `while True or user_option != 'q':` and add the rest of your code (`print(play()`), but in those cases, you could practice by adding an interactive menu with some options like `print('1*) rock', '2*) paper', '3*) scissor', sep='\n')` and **input**, using numbers is just optional but if you store this values in a `queue` or `list` it could be more optimal to manage results or player score.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the game automatically start a new round without asking the players if they want to play again, you can remove the part of the code that asks for player input and simply have the game loop back to the beginning after each round. Here's one way to do that:

```
while True:
    # Get player input
    player1 = input("Player 1, make your move (rock, paper, scissors): ")
    player2 = input("Player 2, make your move (rock, paper, scissors): ")

    # Determine the winner
    if player1 == player2:
        print("It's a tie!")
    elif player1 == "rock" and player2 == "scissors":
        print("Player 1 wins!")
    elif player1 == "paper" and player2 == "rock":
        print("Player 1 wins!")
    elif player1 == "scissors" and player2 == "paper":
        print("Player 1 wins!")
    else:
        print("Player 2 wins!")

    # Start a new round automatically
    print("Starting a new round...")
```